# LINQ - Preserve order across objects with .Any()?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I am building a search function which needs to return a list ordered by relevance.

```
IList<ProjectDTO> projects = new List<ProjectDTO>();
projects = GetSomeProjects();

List<ProjectDTO> rawSearchResults = new List<ProjectDTO>();

//<snip> - do the various search functions here and write to the rawSearchResults

//now take the raw list of projects and group them into project number and 
//number of search returns.
//we will sort by number of search returns and then last updated date
var orderedProjects = rawSearchResults.GroupBy(x => x.ProjectNbr)
                                      .Select(x => new
                                      {
                                          Count = x.Count(),
                                          ProjectNbr = x.Key,
                                          LastUpdated = x.First().UpdatedDateTime
                                      })
                                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                                      .ThenByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated);
```

So far so good; the "orderedProjects" variable returns my list in the correct order.  However, I need the entire object for the next step.  When I try to query back to get the original object type, my results lose their order.  In retrospect, this makes sense, but I need to find a way around it.

```
projects = (from p in projects
            where orderedProjects.Any(o => o.ProjectNbr == p.ProjectNbr)
            select p).ToList();
```

Is there a LINQ-friendly method for preserving the order in the above projects query?

I can loop through the orderedProject list and get each item, but that's not very efficient.  I can also rebuild the entire object in the original orderedProjects query, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong type of solution. Consider how to get the stuff you want out of `orderedProjects` instead.

Comment: Not quite sure on your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it the other way around:
Query `orderedProjects` and select the corresponding items from `projects`:

```
var projects = 
    orderedProjects
        .Select(o => projects.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProjectNbr == o.ProjectNbr))
        .Where(x => x != null) // This is only necessary if there can be
                               // ProjectNbrs in orderedProjects that are not in
                               // projects
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, that works beautifully.  I tried to reverse the query but couldn't get it to work -- I think I was making it too hard!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use "Select" in the middle there as that operator transforms the object into another type and you say that you need the original object.

```
var orderedProjects = rawSearchResults.GroupBy(x => x.ProjectNbr)                                      
                                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                                  .ThenByDescending(x => x.First().UpdatedDateTime);
```

Do they come in chronological order or something? Otherwise, I'm pretty sure you want the "ThenByDescending" to be performed on the newest or oldest project update like so:

```
var orderedProjects = rawSearchResults.GroupBy(x => x.ProjectNbr)                                      
                                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                                  .ThenByDescending(x => x.Max(p=>p.UpdatedDateTime));
```